# SQL Server stored procedure with while condition containing table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table where the name of the country changes regularly, like my_table_US_NA, my_table_CAN_NA, my_table_MEX_NA and so on:

```
create table my_table_US_NA(id int)
insert into my_table_US_NA(id) values (1)
insert into my_table_US_NA(id) values (2)
insert into my_table_US_NA(id) values (3)
insert into my_table_US_NA(id) values (4)

select * from my_table_US_NA

id
----
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure my_looping_procedure (@Country varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare @MyTable varchar(50), @COUNTER int

    set @COUNTER = 1
    set @MyTable = concat('my_table_', @Country, '_NA')

    while (@COUNTER <= (select max(id) from @MyTable))
    begin
        set @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
        print @COUNTER
    end
end
```

When I try to compile the procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure my_looping_procedure, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the table variable "@MyTable"

I tried moving the while loop into its own little variable:

```
create procedure my_looping_procedure (@Country varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare @MyTable varchar(50),
            @sql_loop varchar(max),
            @COUNTER int

    set @COUNTER = 1
    set @MyTable = concat('my_table_', @Country, '_NA')

    -- inner variable here
    select @sql_loop = '
while (' + @COUNTER + '<= (select max(id) from ' + @MyTable + '))
    begin
        set ' + @COUNTER + ' = ' + @COUNTER + ' + 1
        print ' + @COUNTER + '
    end'

    exec(@sql_loop)
end
```

That compiles but returns an error when I try to execute it `exec my_looping_procedure`:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure my_looping_procedure, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 26]
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'WHILE (' to data type int.

I tried declaring and setting all the variables inside `@sql_loop`:

```
alter procedure my_looping_procedure (@Country varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare @sql_loop varchar(max)

    select @sql_loop = '
declare 
@MyTable varchar(50),
@COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER = 1
set @MyTable = concat(''my_table_'', ' + @Country + ', ''_NA'')

WHILE (@COUNTER <= (select max(id) from ' + @MyTable + '))
    BEGIN   
        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
        print @COUNTER
    end'
exec(@sql_loop)
end
```

This compiles but still errors on execution:

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
>   Must declare the table variable "@MyTable".

I then declared the @MyTable variable in the beginning again:

```
alter procedure my_looping_procedure (@Country varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare 
            @MyTable varchar(50),
            @sql_loop varchar(max)

    set @MyTable = concat('my_table_', @Country, '_NA')

    select @sql_loop = '
declare 
@MyTable varchar(50),
@COUNTER INT,
@Country varchar(10),
SET @COUNTER = 1
set @MyTable = concat(''my_table_'', ' + @Country + ', ''_NA'')

WHILE (@COUNTER <= (select max(id) from ' + @MyTable + ' ))
    BEGIN   
        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
        print @COUNTER
    end'

    exec(@sql_loop)
end
```

This actually compiles but complains about the country:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
>   Invalid column name 'US'.

Finally, I commented out the initial table set statement:

```
alter procedure my_looping_procedure (@Country varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare
            @MyTable varchar(50),
            @sql_loop varchar(max)
    -- set @MyTable = concat('my_table_', @Country, '_NA')

    select @sql_loop = '
declare 
@MyTable varchar(50),
@COUNTER INT,
@Country varchar(10),
@MaxCount int
SET @COUNTER = 1
set @MyTable = concat(''my_table_'', ' + @Country + ', ''_NA'')

WHILE (@COUNTER <= (select max(id) from ' + @MyTable + ' ))
    BEGIN   
        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
        print @COUNTER
    end'

    exec(@sql_loop)
end
```

This compiles AND runs, but does nothing.

Can anybody figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Some background:
This is an example of the problem with the parameter and the while loop, not the actual code. As for why it's done this way, the initial design was just for one hard-coded country. When more countries were added, the scripts were copied with new countries hard-coded. 
The initial designer is no longer with the company. My current task is just to make a generic piece of code that can be used no matter how many more countries we add. There are hundreds of scripts like this and very little time and few resources on the project.

I genuinely appreciate the suggestions of using a temp table, but the tables are used in other processes. Until we iron out the underlying issues with the process, we are stuck with this design.

Comment: I see a bunch of code but no question.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: This seems like the design is your problem, not the (very injection open code). There shouldn't be a table for each counter, there should be a single table, with a column for the country. Also, for is the purpose of the `LOOP` here? All you do is `PRINT` each ID; which is you *really* wanted to do doesn't need a loop.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: In fact, why are you declaring variables like `@Country` at all. I (foolishly) assumed they are parameters, but that aren't.

Comment: This is an example of the problem with the parameter and the while loop, not the actual code, because the code deals with financial information for my employer. As for why it's done this way, I inherited the design from someone who is no longer with the company.

Comment: To clarify per Larnu's question, I am trying to put a parameter int the while expression: while (@COUNTER <= (select max(id) from @MyTable))

Comment: So did either of the answers below help you? And if not, what is missing from them?

Comment: @Dale K, No, sadly, neither of the answers below helped. My concern was putting a variable into the WHILE expression, ```WHILE (@COUNTER <= (select max(id) from ' + @MyTable + ' ))```, not the use of a temp table in place of multiple tables nor the worry of a SQL injection attack. 
I apologize for not being clear in my initial post.

Comment: @JenniferMeyer my solution does indeed to what you are suggesting. The only way to achieve it is with dynamic SQL as you worked out, and all I have done is taken one of your examples and got it working, and it produces the results you were after. So perhaps you could be more specific about what isn't working with it?

Comment: In fact user212514's answer is probably better - just add quotename to make it safe.

Answer (score 2):

Without questioning why you are doing it this way (but those comments are very useful and should be carefully considered). Here is your working code:

```
create table #my_table_US_NA(id int);

insert into #my_table_US_NA(id) values (1),(2),(3),(4);

declare @MyTable varchar(50), @Country varchar(10);
set @Country = 'US';
set @MyTable = quotename(concat('#my_table_', @Country, '_NA'));

declare @Sql nvarchar(max) = 'declare @COUNTER INT = 1; WHILE (@COUNTER <= (select max(id) from [' + @MyTable + ']))
    BEGIN   
        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
        print @COUNTER
    end';

exec(@Sql);

drop table #my_table_US_NA;
```

Note 1: I've added `quotename` as per Larnu's suggestion to avoid the possibility of injection.

Note 2: Your table design doesn't align with how relational databases are intended to be used. You wouldn't normally have a separate table for each country, you would normally have a country column which allows you to segment the table by country. No good design should end up relying on dynamic SQL, sure you might need it for some edge cases but not your main business flow.

Comment: That I agree with. When you need to use Dynamic SQL for what should be a simple query, you know that you have a (very) flawed design.

Comment: Using separate tables to store the same data for a different location is asking for trouble. I can't begin to imagine the complexity it introduces in other aspects of the system.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with all of the comments regarding poor design. With any luck, the project will continue long enough to to fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to gather the data from the country-specific table and then loop through the country-specific data.  I would take the approach of using a "temp" table so that you can insert data from a dynamic SQL statement.  Here's what I mean:

```
create procedure my_looping_procedure as
begin
create table #MyTable (id int)
declare @COUNTER int, @Country varchar(3), @MyTable varchar(50), @sql varchar(100)

SET @COUNTER = 1
set @Country = 'US'
set @MyTable = concat('my_table_', @Country, '_NA')
set @sql = 'insert #MyTable (id) select * from ' + @MyTable
exec(@sql)

WHILE (@COUNTER<= (select max(id) from #MyTable))
    BEGIN   
        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
        print @COUNTER
    end
end
go
exec my_looping_procedure
```

Comment: This has the same problem i mentioned in Dale's answer. This will be open to injection *if* this becomes parametrised,

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resolved the issue by declaring the expression inside the while loop as a text string, like so: `set @WhileExpr = concat('@COUNTER <= (select max(id) from ', @MyTable)` then using it inside the while parenthesis `WHILE (' + @WhileExpr + '))`

I apologize for wasting your time.