# Dynamic query that will store dates from various table into a tmp yields NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameters

**Story:**

Trying to get the minimum date of a column from various tables (column names have the same name).

I figured out how to get the value but storing the value in the tmp table doesn't work.

Currently trying it with one table only to see if the mechanics works.

**What I have:**

```
create table #t2 (date datetime)
declare @date datetime, @sql nvarchar(max);
begin
    set @sql = 'SELECT MAX(insert_stamp) FROM game_install'+';'
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@x datetime out', @date out
    insert into #t2 SELECT @date
end

select * from #t2
```

**And the results are:**

```
+-------------------------+
|    (No column name)     |
+-------------------------+
| 2019-07-24 04:16:06.000 |
+-------------------------+

+------+
| date |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

**Why isn't the table populated with the date result?**

Comment: Why does this need dynamic SQL at all? There's nothing dynamic about your statement

Comment: @Larnu my understanding is that its a proof of concept so SO can iterate through a list of tables to obtain the desired info.

Comment: Then the OP should probably show how they are creating the entire statement, as I **assume** they aren't foolishly looping through them, @DaleK :)

Comment: @RogerSteinberg Do read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040770/sql-server-stored-procedure-with-while-condition-containing-table-variable/59040878#59040878) question and answer which addresses some issues when looping through tables using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the variable i.e. `@x =` in the select

Also best practice to list the columns being inserted.

```
create table #t2 (date datetime)
declare @date datetime, @sql nvarchar(max);

begin
    set @sql = 'SELECT @x = MAX(created) FROM proposal'+';'
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@x datetime out', @date out
    insert into #t2(date) SELECT @date
end

--  But you can also do it in one statement
begin
    set @sql = 'insert into #t2 (date) SELECT MAX(created) FROM proposal'+';'
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@date datetime out', @date out
end

select * from #t2

drop table #t2
```

Gives:

```
date
2019-11-28 19:40:00.000
2019-11-28 19:40:00.000
```